# Como inverter valores que estão separados por vírgula no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Foto da minha base:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados estão assim:

```
-46.63642120299626,-23.54854965191239,0
```

Preciso selecionar para que fiquem invertidos:

Ex:

```
-23.54854965191239,0,-46.63642120299626
```

Minha seleção no php:

```
<?php
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabela")or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
      $name = $row['nome'];
      $latlng = $row['latlng'];
      $desc = $row['desc'];
      echo("addMarker($latlng, '<b>$name</b><br />');\n");
   }
?>
```

Comment: Esse inversão de valores(LOL) tem alguma regra?

Comment: Então, vamos ver se você consegue me ajudar, eu preciso inverter para ficar neste formato:-23.54854965191239,-46.63642120299626 não tem nenhuma regra em especifico. Que tipo de regra você diz, para que eu possa entender melhor?

Answer (score 5):

Se os dados estão vindo diretamente na string, basta fazer isso:

```
<?php
// se: "-46.63642120299626,-23.54854965191239,0"
// está na variável: $row['latlng']

    $params = explode(',', $row['latlng']);
    $lat = $params[0]; //-46.63642120299626
    $lon = $params[1]; //-23.54854965191239
    $val = $params[2]; //0

    $saida = $lon.','.$val.','.$lat;

?>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: @HenriqueS.Santos. Legal que a resposta lhe ajudou,  se puder marcar a setinha verde. Agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Use o método `explode` para separar por `,` e depois só reorganizar.

```
<?php
    $partes = explode(',', $row['latlng']);
    $latlng = $partes[0].",".$partes[2].",".$partes[1];
?>
```